# AS3 Google Maps labels and infoWindow offset

Tags: actionscript-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two problems.

1 ) I have a google map with a marker and the label applied to it goes right through the center of the marker.  Ideally I would like it above the marker, but at this point I'll take anything.  Here's what I have.

```
var m:Marker = new Marker(new LatLng(tempLat,tempLang),new MarkerOptions({label:"Hello World"}))
```

2 ) I have the same problem with the infoWindow.  It completely covers the marker.  Here's the code.

```
map.openInfoWindow(new LatLng(tempLat,tempLang), new InfoWindowOptions({title: "Hello", content: "World"}))
```

Thank You.

Comment: What library are you using for Google Maps in AS3? The official library was deprecated in September 2011 and will cease to work at all in September of this year. If that is the API you are using, you should really look at alternatives since it won't work in a few months. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/

Comment: I am using the Google 1.8b API.  It's a long story, but our system won't support a JS Map unit until next month, and we're doing this for a client in the mean time.  Once this project is over we'll definitely cut over to the JS solution.  But in the mean time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any answer for the marker label, but for the InfoWindow this is what I have.

map.openInfoWindow(new LatLng(tempLat,tempLang), new InfoWindowOptions({title: storeName, content: to.text, hasTail:true, pointOffset: new Point(0, -40)}));